# Select SQL by group

Tags: sql-server

I try to select with calculate by group but I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'dbo.LN0617.RATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can someone help me?

```
SELECT
    NT4                AS nt,
    LN0617.OFFCR       AS OfficeCode,
    ln0617.RATE * 100  AS LaiSuat,
    SUM( ln0617.CBAL ) AS SoDu,
    ln0617.RATE * 100 * sum( ln0617.CBAL ) AS LS1
FROM
    [dbo].[SIL_CM] 
    JOIN [dbo].[LN0617] ON
    (
        ln0617.ACCTNO = SIL_CM.TK
        AND
        ln0617.CBAL <> 0
        AND
        SIL_CM.TKTYPE='L'
    )
GROUP BY
    sil_cm.NT4,
    LN0617.OFFCR,
    ln0617.RATE * 100
ORDER BY
    LN0617.OFFCR,
    ln0617.RATE * 100
```

Comment: You should use **group by ln0617.RATE**

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem I see in your select list is the following line:

```
ln0617.RATE*100*sum(ln0617.CBAL) as LS1
```

SQL Server may be complaining about `ln0617.RATE` because it is being mixed with an aggregate function.  One option here would be to move `ln0617.RATE` inside the summation:

```
select
    NT4 as nt,
    LN0617.OFFCR as OfficeCode,
    ln0617.RATE*100 as LaiSuat,
    sum(ln0617.CBAL) as SoDu,
    100*sum(ln0617.RATE * ln0617.CBAL) as LS1
from [dbo].[SIL_CM]
...
```

This should work because multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to refer to the column for grouping as * 100 is constant

```
SELECT
      NT4                                               AS nt
    , LN0617.OFFCR                                      AS OfficeCode
    , ln0617.RATE * 100                                 AS LaiSuat
    , SUM(ln0617.CBAL)                                  AS SoDu
    , SUM(ln0617.CBAL * ln0617.RATE) / SUM(ln0617.cbal) AS LS1
FROM [dbo].[SIL_CM] SIL_CM
JOIN [dbo].[LN0617] LN0617 ON ln0617.ACCTNO = SIL_CM.TK
WHERE ln0617.CBAL <> 0
      AND SIL_CM.TKTYPE = 'L'
GROUP BY
      sil_cm.NT4
    , LN0617.OFFCR
    , ln0617.RATE
ORDER BY
      LN0617.OFFCR
    , ln0617.RAT
```